# How do I check for equals in my lottery ticket?

Tags: c#, equality

In class we are currently making lottery tickets as a project, I'm currently stuck on a question with equals:
The same rows are not allowed to appear multiple times on the same ticket.

I have tried a couple of things, but nothing has been working yet.

```
public class TalRækker //rows
{
    static Random rnd = new Random();
    public static int[,] Line()
    {
        int[,] line = new int[10, 7];
        //int x = rnd.Next(1, 36);

        for (int i = 0; i < line.GetLength(0); i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < line.GetLength(1); j++)
            {
                line[i, j] = rnd.Next(1, 36);
            }
        }
        return line;


    }
    public static void Print2DArray<T>(T[,] line)
    {
        var lineNumber = 1;
        for (int i = 0; i < line.GetLength(0); i++)
        {
            Console.Write(" {0:D2}.\t", lineNumber);
            for(int j = 0; j < line.GetLength(1); j++)
            {
                Console.Write("{0:D2} ", line[i, j]);
            }
            Console.WriteLine();
            lineNumber++;
        }
    }
```

I've updated my code to the following but still getting an issue:

```
namespace lottery 
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("\t  Lotto " + DateTime.Now.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy"));
            Console.WriteLine("\t" + "\t1-uge");             
            Console.WriteLine("\t      LYN-LOTTO\t");             
            Console.WriteLine(" ");            
            TalRækker.Print2DArray(TalRækker.?()); //here is the problem
            Console.WriteLine("");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I assume that the same number isn't allowed more than once in the same row? You're not checking for that either.

Answer (score 1):

I would be tempted to use a jagged array to make this a little easier to handle. I'd then split the functionality required into separate methods to allow recursion if there are duplicates:

```
    static Random rnd = new Random();
    public static int[][] GenerateTicket(int numberOfRows, int rowLength)
    {
        var lines = new int[numberOfRows][];

        for (int i =0; i < lines.Length; i++)
        {
            lines[i] = GenerateLine(rowLength, lines);
        }

        return lines;
    }

    public static int[] GenerateLine(int rowLength, int[][] existingLines)
    {
        var newLine = new int[rowLength];
        for (int j = 0; j < rowLength; j++)
        {
            newLine[j] = GenerateNumber(newLine);
        }

        var orderedLine = newLine.OrderBy(n => n).ToArray();
        var exists = existingLines.Where(line => line != null).Any(line => line.SequenceEqual(orderedLine));

        // If a line already exists, call the method again to generate a new line, otherwise return the line.
        return exists ? GenerateLine(rowLength, existingLines) : orderedLine;
    }

    public static int GenerateNumber(int[] line)
    {
        var number = rnd.Next(1, 36);
        // Check if the line already contains the number, if so, call the method again to generate a new number, otherwise return the number.
        return line.Contains(number) ? GenerateNumber(line) : number;
    }

    public static void Print2DArray<T>(T[][] lines)
    {
        var lineNumber = 1;
        for (int i=0; i < lines.Length; i++)
        {
            Console.Write(" {0:D2}.\t", lineNumber);
            lineNumber++;
            for (int j = 0; j < lines[i].Length; j++)
            {
                Console.Write("{0:D2} ", lines[i][j]);
            }
            Console.WriteLine();
        }
    }
```

***Update***

I've sorted the newLine before using SequenceEqual, so that this will compare previously ordered lines with this and therefore return true/false correctly.

Comment: hi, thank you for the help, i like this wau of solving it, makes a bit more sense to me as a newbie.
the thing is, when i try to call it from my main program, i cant get it to work with the way you have made it.

Comment: the code, im new to the website so making it in code format is confusing xD

`code
namespace lottery
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("\t  Lotto " + DateTime.Now.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy"));
            Console.WriteLine("\t" + "\t1-uge");
            Console.WriteLine("\t      LYN-LOTTO\t");
            Console.WriteLine(" ");
            TalRækker.Print2DArray(TalRækker.?());//here is the problem
            Console.WriteLine("");
        }
    }
}`

Comment: You need to use 'GenerateTicket' before you try and print anything.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that this is an array exercise. Otherwise I would prefer to use a List.

So you could do something similar to the following. Please note how each function follows the single responsibility principle and usage of access modifiers.

It is a good use case here for Do-While loop as your condition depends on the first outcome of row generation.

I did not check the occurrence of the same number in a row as you did not state that in your question.

```
public class TalRækker
{
    static Random rnd = new Random();
    public static int[,] GenerateLotteryTicket(int totalLines, int lineLength)
    {
        
        int[,] lines = new int[totalLines, lineLength];
        int[] newLine = new int[lineLength];


        for (int i = 0; i < totalLines; i++)
        {
            do
            {
                newLine = GenerateLine(lineLength);
            }
            while (ExistInTicket(lines,newLine));

            for (int j = 0; j < lineLength; j++)
            {
                lines[i,j] = newLine[j];
            }
        }
        return lines;
    }

    private static int[] GenerateLine(int lineLength)
    {
        int[] row = new int[lineLength];
        for (int i = 0; i < lineLength; i++)
        {
            row[i] = rnd.Next(1, 36);
        }
        return row;
    }
    private static bool ExistInTicket(int[,] ticket, int[] line)
    {
        bool rowMatchFound;
        for(int i = 0; i < ticket.GetLength(0); i++)
        {
            rowMatchFound = true;
            for (int j = 0; j < ticket.GetLength(1); j++)
            {
                if(ticket[i,j] != line[j])
                {
                    rowMatchFound = false;
                    break;
                }
            }
            if(rowMatchFound) return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    public static void Print2DArray<T>(T[,] line)
    {
        var lineNumber = 1;
        for (int i = 0; i < line.GetLength(0); i++)
        {
            Console.Write(" {0:D2}.\t", lineNumber);
            for (int j = 0; j < line.GetLength(1); j++)
            {
                Console.Write("{0:D2} ", line[i, j]);
            }
            Console.WriteLine();
            lineNumber++;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Take the numbers 1 to 35 and put them in a List. For each row, randomly sort the numbers and then take the first 7. Build a "key" from those numbers by sorting them and separating them by a delimiter such as a comma. If that key doesn't exist in a HashSet then it is a unique row. Add it to the HashSet and copy the numbers over to your array. Repeat until you've got all 10 rows:

```
public static int[,] Line()
{
    int[,] line = new int[10, 7];
    HashSet<String> rows = new HashSet<String>();
    var numbers = Enumerable.Range(1, 35).ToList();            
    for (int i = 0; i < line.GetLength(0); i++)
    {
        int[] row;
        String rowKey;
        do
        {
            row = numbers.OrderBy(x => rnd.Next())
                .Take(line.GetLength(1)).ToList()
                .OrderBy(x => x).ToArray();
            rowKey = String.Join(",", row);
        } while (rows.Contains(rowKey));                
        rows.Add(rowKey);

        for (int j = 0; j < line.GetLength(1); j++)
        {
            line[i, j] = row[j];
        }
    }
    return line;
}
```